# KineticJS: set a maximum number for cloned objects

Tags: kineticjs

How do I set a maximum number to limit the cloned objects? The project requires putting this kind of conditions to make sure to have a reasonable number of items (equipments, doors, sensors in the house, etc).

Any suggestions, tips, ideas?

Comment: Provide more details please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/8A9sP/

You can attach a `maxClones` property to your original object.

```
var circle1 = new Kinetic.Circle({
    x:50,
    y:75,
    radius: 30,
    fill: 'red',
    stroke: 'black',
    strokeWidth: 4,
    draggable: true
});

// add a property defining the max # clones available from this original object

circle1.maxClones=3;
```

Then when cloning you can use this property to control the max number of clones made:

```
if(circle1.maxClones>0){
    layer.add(circle1.clone({x:circle1.maxClones*50+100}));
    layer.draw();
    circle1.maxClones--;
}else{
    alert("Cloning Unavailable: max clone count has been reached.");
}
```